# Compile with referenced but unused assemblies(.net)

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, .net-assembly, csc

I need to compile some C# scripts with a command tool(csc.exe). And I was wondering if I can add a whole bunch of assemblies from which those scripts might reference some. I've tested with this trick and the other way(adding specified references), and see no difference(with my eyes lol).
I googled and only saw some posts say it is better to remove unused references(which apparently I already know). And in my case, somebody has got an idea?

**I think the compiler will probably grab whatever those scripts need(used) from the assemblies I offered and leave alone other(unused) assemblies. Am I right?**

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, adding a bunch of unused references to your application makes the startup of the application slow. That's because it takes time for the CLR to load each module. Furthermore It's more likely for you to get conflicts when using a class which exists with the same name in two assemblies.In ReSharper (an extension) you can remove the unused references,

Comment: @MohammadChamanpara In my case, it's not a **project**. I compiled with this trick and checked the resulted assembly with decompiler, and didn't see any unused assembly reference in its referenced assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

I think that each unused referenced is being loaded first time its used. So more reference makes no difference